# How to write if on this function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How to write if when dz_mc then text is when dz2_mc the text change to another. Is this posible or i must search for another solutin...

```
function (event:Event){
dz_mc.hitTestPoint(Star.x, Star.y, true)) {
       deepText.text = "Dziļums no 0,5m - 1m";
dz2_mc.hitTestPoint(Star.x, Star.y, true)) {
       deepText.text = "Dziļums no 1m - 2m";
dz3_mc.hitTestPoint(Star.x, Star.y, true)) {
       deepText.text = "Dziļums no 2m - 2,5m";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function (event:Event){

    var output:String = "";

    if(dz_mc.hitTestPoint(Star.x, Star.y, true)) {
        output = "Dziļums no 0,5m - 1m";
    } else if( dz2_mc.hitTestPoint(Star.x, Star.y, true)) {
        output = "Dziļums no 1m - 2m";
    } else if (dz3_mc.hitTestPoint(Star.x, Star.y, true)) {
        output = "Dziļums no 2m - 2,5m";
    }

    deepText.text = output;
}
```

Comment: Parameter text must be non-null.
 at flash.text::TextField/set text()

Comment: So change this line: `var output:String;` like this: `var output:String = "";`